# MySQL Date range query not working

Tags: mysql, database, datetime, filtering

I have a form table which has following structure

```
->id
->input_date
->form_num
->name
->address
```

My `input_date` format is dataype `DATETIME` with a format like

```
2015-12-29 12:45:08
```

I am making a reporting module with date range filter so my query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM golden_leaves.forms 
WHERE input_date >= '2015-02-01 00:00:35' AND input_date <= '2016-02-11 23:08:39' 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

so basically I want to get Feb 01 to Feb 11. But when I query it, my data from december, january is also included? Input dates dating back from Dec 2015 is also fetched? I also tried

```
WHERE input_date BETWEEN '2015-02-01 00:00:35' AND '2016-02-11 23:08:39' ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Same thing. In my postgres database this works fine.

Comment: Maybe because you start from 2015 year?

Comment: Dec 2015 is >= '2015-02-01 00:00:35'

Comment: God, I am so sorry I missed that one. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your start date - you are querying dates since February 2015, not 2016:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     golden_leaves.forms 
WHERE    input_date >= '2016-02-01 00:00:35' AND 
         -- Here ----------^
         input_date <= '2016-02-11 23:08:39' 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second date is before your first date (Try reversing the order of the dates)

WHERE input_date BETWEEN '2016-02-11 23:08:39' AND '2015-02-01 00:00:35' ORDER BY id DESC;

Comment: The syntax of between **requires** that the first vslue is less than the second value. Your answer would always result in no records.